# Mediawiki Html Extension check open tags

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any mediawiki extension which can help me determine if i have any html open tags while saving the mediawiki content.
The reason I am looking for this extension is, if i have any of the html tags open, it eats up the category tags at the bottom of the page where we show all the category tags 
I need something like this http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder which will find open tags and alert the user

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable Tidy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgTidyConfig) which will automatically clean up the HTML.